# How to hide parts of an image but show by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am looking to find out how i can display a background image, but then have parts of the image hidden so that it can be expanded by the user if need be. The reason being is that the height of the image is quite long and i want to be able to reduce this and make this interactive.

I have seen something similar on the following site, although this uses a parallax image, mine will just be a static image.

https://www.laduree.com/en_gb/

I would love to know the name of this feature and how something like this can be implemented.

If somebody could please help.

Comment: If you set a `max-height` on the containing element, smaller than the height of the background-image, you'll notice the rest of the image being cropped out or trimmed. Then you can add an on-click event to adjust the `max-height` rule and display the rest of the image. You can do the same with a `:hover`. Have you experimented with this method?

Comment: I haven't unfortunately, will start now..